# Android Application finish prob

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, dialog

I am using a custom Alert dialog. If user go with negative button of the code I need the close the app totally. I am using following code.

```
public class TestApp extends TabActivity {

    private int tabid = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab

        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab
        Intent myint = this.getIntent();
        tabid = myint.getIntExtra("tab_id", 0);

        .......................
        .........................
        .......................


        tabHost.setCurrentTab(tabid);

        showReward(this);
    }

    private void showReward(Context c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        AlertDialog alertDialog;
        Context mContext = c;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.title);
        text.setText("Sample text");
        text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        TextView msg = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.msg);
        msg.setText("Sample text.");
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setView(layout);        
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Log.d(null,"step1");
                dialog.cancel();
                Log.d(null,"step2");
                closeApp();
            }
        });
        alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private void closeApp(){
        Log.d(null,"step3");
        this.finish();
    }


}
```

But it is working perfectly before to add showReward() function. When u add the function, the dialog box is appearing perfectly. If we click on the negative button it is giving NullpointerException due to "Unable to destroy activity". Whats the problem with my code?

Comment: @user525004: "I need the close the app totally" -- there is no such concept as this in Android, any more than there is in Web apps. "it is giving NullpointerException due to 'Unable to destroy activity'" -- I suspect that you are mis-reading your stack trace. Please consider posting the stack trace by editing your question.

Comment: Ya....i need to close the very activity. Thats all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is problem related to cursor.close() at the time finish. No such close during finish()

Answer (score -1):

Please show the stacktrace of your error.

Taking a wild guess without seeing the stacktrace I'd say that calling `this.finish()` (instead of `finish()`) is your problem as "this" probably does not refer to the activity you're trying to end.

Also see this link:
http://www.connorgarvey.com/blog/?p=93
where something similar is accomplished.